# Entity Relationship Multiple 1:1's

Tags: ado.net, frameworks, entity, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an application where I have a generic object (table) called Hull.  Each hull in the table is unique.

I have another object that has three hulls, but they are specifically the Port_Hull, Center_Hull and Starboard_Hull.

Rather than create a One to Many relationship, I was trying to create a one to one relationship for each one, but this results in numerous errors unless I make the relationship from Hull to Vessel one to many (which it is not).  Any idea how I go about this, or should I abandon the concept and make the vessel to hull relationship one to many and deal with lists that always have three entries?

p.s. Using uniqueidentifiers as many users can be adding records while disconnected.

Hull Table

- HullID   uniqueidentifier  (primary key)
- plus bunch of hull data fields

Vessel Table

- VesselID  uniqueidentifier  (primary key)
- MainHullID uniqueidentifier  (tried as key and non-key)
- PortHullID uniqueidentifier
- StarboardHullID uniqueidentifier
- plus bunch of Vessel data fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this 1:1 in two different ways:

1. Add a unique constraint for each invidivual Hull field in Vessel, i.e. MainHull, PortHull, StarboardHull. This will ensure that a Hull can only be used by one Vessel.
2. Remove the Hull fields from vessel, and add a new field to Hull -  Vessel. This then explicitly names the vessel that this hull belongs to. It would also seem to make sense to then add a HullType to Hull, so you know what type of hull it is. A unique constraint on HullType+Vessel will ensure that each vessel gets at most one hull of each type (but unfortunately, can have 0 of a given type.)

I would go for the first one. since it seems more natural to select a vessel and then find the associated hulls, and also ensures that each vessel has the 3 hulls required (assmining a non-null constraint on MainHull, PortHull, StarboardHull.)

EDIT: Seeing your comment, and given that vessels don't need 3 hulls, then the second solution is also worth considering. If you need to add additional types of hull, you do this without changing your schema, since the hull type is not inferred from the field it is referenced, but named explicitly in the proposed 'HullType' field.

Comment: The issue with approach one (I think), is not every vessel has all three hulls (I simplified my original post). <br/>
Some vessels are monohulls and only have the Mainhull and some vessels are catamarans and have the PortHull and StarboardHull.<br/>
I am wondering if for the Hull table I should make the primary key the VesselID field plus a 1 char field for hull (M, P & S), make the relationship between the two tables one to many with a foreign key index on VesselID, then deal with the relationship in coding?

Comment: I'd keep a surrogate HullID on Hull - you don't want composite PKs - a real pain in the rear. Instead, create a unique constraint over both VesselID and your M,P,S char field - what I called HullType in my answer. That way, you ensure a vessel has at most one hull of any given type. Now, weather a hull of a given type makes sense for a given vessel is another question, which you can resolve simply in code (possible in db model, but complex) You've got a complex domain model that you're mapping to the database - have you considered using a Object-Relational Mapping tool, e.g. NHibernate?

Comment: LOL - I am trying to use the VisualStudio entity framework tool, if it would just quit giving me strange errors and recognize things line enumerators.  Does NHibernate for .net add functionality to the standard framework?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking whether it is possible to create this or whether you ought to create this?

First, it is possible:

```
Create Table Vessel
(
    VesselId uniqueidentifier not null primary key
    , MainHullId uniqueidentifier not null
    , PortHullId uniqueidentifier not null
    , StarboardHullId uniqueidentifier not null
    , ...
    , Constraint FK_Vessel_Hull_Main
        Foreign Key ( MainHullId )
        References Hull( HullId )
    , Constraint FK_Vessel_Hull_Port
        Foreign Key ( PortHullId )
        References Hull( HullId )
    , Constraint FK_Vessel_Hull_Startboard
        Foreign Key ( StarboardHullId )
        References Hull( HullId )
    , Constraint UC_Vessal_MainHullId Unique ( MainHullId )
    , Constraint UC_Vessal_PortHullId Unique ( PortHullId )
    , Constraint UC_Vessal_StarboardHullId Unique ( StarboardHullId )
)
```

A 1:1 relationship is created when you have a child table with a foreign key to a parent table and the foreign key is required to be unique.

Now, as to whether it is a good design, that would depend on the problem domain. It seems odd to have a vessal with three different hulls based on left, right and center but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, actually, both questions.

But as to your second question.  Each hull can contain different components (tanks, engines, etc) and indeed can be different sizes (also captured).  Ie. A typical Trimaran has  a larger center hull and two smaller port and starboard hulls.

I had actually simplified my question, because I also have Vessels which are monohulls and catamarans which have two hulls.  I create different entity objects off the same database table for monohulls, catamarans and trimarans based on a vesseltype field.  The methods for the three types assume different business rules.